# Magento EE PayPal IPN issue: PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php on line 532

Tags: magento-enterprise, paypal-standard

We've received an e-mail from PayPal alerting us that our IPN page is returning a lot of 500 errors. We've investigated the various error logs and found the following error within the /var/log/nginx directory. The full directory path has been removed for obvious reasons.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function save() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php on line 532"
```

We're running Magento Enterprise 1.13.0.2 and the method which contains line 532 is located within the following function.

```
/**
 * Process completed payment (either full or partial)
 *
 * @param bool $skipFraudDetection
 */
protected function _registerPaymentCapture($skipFraudDetection = false)
{
    if ($this->getRequestData('transaction_entity') == 'auth') {
        return;
    }
    $parentTransactionId = $this->getRequestData('parent_txn_id');
    $this->_importPaymentInformation();
    $payment = $this->_order->getPayment();
    $payment->setTransactionId($this->getRequestData('txn_id'))
        ->setPreparedMessage($this->_createIpnComment(''))
        ->setParentTransactionId($parentTransactionId)
        ->setShouldCloseParentTransaction('Completed' === $this->getRequestData('auth_status'))
        ->setIsTransactionClosed(0)
        ->registerCaptureNotification(
            $this->getRequestData('mc_gross'),
            $skipFraudDetection && $parentTransactionId
        );
    $this->_order->save();

    // notify customer
    $invoice = $payment->getCreatedInvoice();
    if ($invoice && !$this->_order->getEmailSent()) {
        $this->_order->sendNewOrderEmail()->addStatusHistoryComment(
            Mage::helper('paypal')->__('Notified customer about invoice #%s.', $invoice->getIncrementId())
        )
        ->setIsCustomerNotified(true)
        ->save();
    }
}
```

Line 532 is the save() method called on the $this->_order->sendNewOrderEmail().... towards the bottom of the function. As testing the IPN is ridiculously hard from a local environment I was wondering if anyone had come across this error before? or if they can point me in the right direction of the issue.

Comment: sendNewOrdrEmail() is normally overwritten by third party extensions sending transactional emails. Maybe that is your issue there if you have another integration to handle emails.

Comment: I would agree with mbalparda, being that Ebay owns Paypal and Magento best bet is on a 3rd party module.  Try disabling community and local code pools to see if the same persists.

Comment: @mbalparda thanks for the advice! I never through of that.

Comment: If this worked let me know so I can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the error appears in the `->save` line, it means that `setIsCustomerNotified(true)` does not return `$this` (the current object).
The only occurence of `setIsCustomerNotified` I found is in the class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Status_History` that returns `return $this->setData('is_customer_notified', $flag);`.

This `setData` method should return the current object.
So something must be overwritten in you instance by a custom module.
Either the `setIsCustomerNotified` method or the `setData` method of the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Status_History` class.

[Here is a simple script](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2013/03/get-class-rewrites.html) that can help you find the overrides in your instance. Look in the output for something related to `Order` or `History`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, I shall investigate and report back. Also thanks for linking the script.

Comment: We found that Xtento_AdvancedOrderStatus_Model_Sales_Order_Status_History was overriding the Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Status_History class and within this there was an override for the method setIsCustomerNotified which was missing a return in front of  parent::setIsCustomerNotified($flag) which would obviously cause this error. 

Now I'm going to have to start checking all my 3rd party modules and verify the developers have common sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You issue might be in the `sendNewOrderEmail()` method. This is usually overwritten by third party extensions handling transactional emails. Check if you have any extension doing that and see if you can disable them for testing.